# I run `sudo apt-get remove python2.7`, can I restore my Ubuntu now?

Tags: restore, python-2.7

I wanted to remove and reinstall python2.7 interpreter on 12.04

But when I did `sudo apt-get remove python2.7`, The crazy terminal started to remove everything!!! Any idea how I can restore whatever I've removed?

Comment: now my unity UI is no longer working, ? icons starts to populate the UI...

Comment: now nothing is working, i have to work on windows...

Comment: Can you boot to the Ubuntu even in the console?

Comment: recovery console works but even apt-get goes crazy with errors...

Comment: Actually, core tools do not have much dependencies beside C libs. Both `apt`/`aptitude` does not depends on python. `apt` just suggests python. Honestly, I was in doubt about that so I tried U12.04 in VBox, uninstalled python2.7 as you did, reboot, unable to login, switch to tty6, I was able reinstall gedit (dep on python) using apt-get, even aptitude is working well. `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` should solve such case. Probably, apt got into unclean state after uninstalling python2.7 was interrupted. Could you post the output/errors you got when running `sudo apt-get install python2.7`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While reinstalling Ubuntu is probably the easiest way, it's worth pointing out that it's possible to recover without reinstalling everything.

To do this, manually download the `python2.7` package (and its dependencies), and manually install them using `dpkg` (bypassing APT, which requires Python). Once that's installed, `apt` should work again, and so `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` will restore your system. (If `apt-get` still doesn't work, you might also need to download and install any missing dependencies.)

In the future, if you need to reinstall a package, instead use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

or

```
sudo aptitude reinstall python2.7
```

which reinstalls the package without having to remove the dependencies.

Comment: BTW, aptitude is gone after removing python. =)

Comment: in case it does not installs the `ubuntu-desktop`, installing it manually is a good idea. In my case i ran the python installation with --reinstall arg, but `ubuntu-desktop` was not there, then i install it using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. It will take a while :)

Comment: This reinstall command was also useful when running pip was throwing some error. The reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

Removing Python is not a good idea as much of Ubuntu depends on it. You may have seen a warning telling you which packages depend on python and thus will be removed with Python. When proceeding you end up with a quite stripped down OS.

Reinstalling Ubuntu would now be the easiest and safest way to get it back. Take care not to delete your HOME when you do so.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think, he can restore the PC if he have still access to TTY. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` should do the job

Comment: any idea how i could reinstall on the root console? that's the only thing accessible now from my ubuntu, how could i reinstall using wubi from windows? (i've backuped my files using ext2read from windows)

Comment: @Anwar I do not think that he will be able to do that, as there are so many pieces of software that depend on python, that it might be impossible to reinstall them all. And I am not talking about the `ubuntu desktop`.

Comment: @Anwar: Applications other than from ubuntu-desktop may depend on Python. They were likely removed as well.

Comment: @NlightNFotis and Takkat, yes i just seen that apt also depends on Python. Thanks.

Comment: @2er0: sorry but I have no experience with Wubi.

Comment: @NlightNFotis, Takkat and Anwar. Though I did apt-get remove python2.7, I did have apt running. I recall that I did have python-minimal which was not removed. So, I could do apt-get install ubuntu-desktop from tty1

Answer (score 4):

If it's not too late for anyone, or if you have come across this problem lately, this is how I got it running:

I followed Mechanical snail's advice and downloaded all the packages using Synaptic. I selected all the relevant packages, basically everything with "python", "python2", "python3", "apt", "python-apt", etc., that was already installed in my computer, tagged them for **reinstallation**, and when I hit **apply**, I made sure I downloaded them only.

Then, under root, I went into the `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder and ran the following command to manually re-install everything I downloaded (you will see all the packages you downloaded with Synaptic in here):

```
dpkg --unpack *.deb
```

Anyway, I was getting this `apt_pkg` error whenever I would get an error message from a Python script in Aptana, and yesterday when I was trying to add a repo. Now at least I can add the repo with no problem, but I'm still getting the `apt_pkg` error whenever there is an error in my Python scripts...

Running the script outside of Aptana by calling `python3.2` or `python3` which points at 3.2 works (meaning I get the script's error without the `apt_pkg` error), but if I run it with `python3.3` then the error is back.

Comment: One addition, it seems that it is a bug and this may shed more light unto the issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1059017

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem.
And I was able to fix it going to ctrl+alt+f1, logged in with my username and password
then:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

And it reinstalled most (if not all) the deleted files (along with unity and terminal)
:D

Comment: same for me with cinnamon

Comment: amazing! my `apt-get` fails to work after i `apt-get remove python`...

Answer (score 2):

In a fit of senseless haste I removed python 2.7 and it removed a lot of packages that were dependent on it. I could not even launch terminal.

I dropped to tty1 and did what Lois Mari Ang Laput suggested

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
> ```

I got back the desktop and could launch terminal. Packages like shutter, mysql-workbench, that were removed needed to be reinstalled.

I checked the history in /var/log/apt and reinstalled all packages that were removed.

Answer (score 1):

you can recover using live CD using `chroot`

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute this: `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
and then `apt-get install gdm`. When asked lightdm or gdm select **gdm**.
*both as root or using sudo*

Comment: by the way, once you `apt-get remove python`, `apt-get` will fail to work and complains endlessly...

Comment: not if you are fast enough and stop this procedure that kills your entire ubuntu

Comment: yeah, i was silly enough to let it run until the point where i figured something smells fishy... hahahahaa

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get purge python && sudo apt-get install python2.7 


sudo apt-get install python-pip`

removes and reinstalls python and pip, then you can install apps like flask, bottle and many others

`eg sudo pip install flask`
 try to install your apps with python

Answer (score 1):

During un-installation of Python, I abruptly closed the terminal. Hence Python was partially removed.
I fixed it with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install –-reinstall python-apt
sudo apt-get install –-reinstall python2.7
```