# Many packages been uninstalled by mistake? How to recover Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I uninstalled Python2.7 first which ended up deleting many dependencies as well. Then trying to fins that problem I ended up deleting more packages. But even from the begining of my installation package manager didnt work. Thats why i wanted to uninstall Python to fix it.

now when I do

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
......
0 upgraded, 0 installed....

sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists...Done
```

Any way wayI can fix this apt-get install and install all the necessary packagers. Now I can oly log into terminal. Windo login fails.

Comment: Backup your data and reinstall. Manually recovering the system at this point will be 1) very time consuming, 2) difficult and 3) error prone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I run \`sudo apt-get remove python2.7\`, can I restore my Ubuntu now?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187227/i-run-sudo-apt-get-remove-python2-7-can-i-restore-my-ubuntu-now)

Comment: could you try sudo apt-get check sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing the last one, with the '--fix-missing' option may help resolve your problem. it saved me big trouble before. if it doesn't work, then reinstall may be the better option.

Comment: everything just says done without much info.. im downloading new version to install , thank you

Comment: OK. since you'll reinstall finally, could you maybe try one more step, just for learning (for me also):  what are in your  /etc/apt/sources.list file, did you accidentally modify it? could you download a default sources.list for your current version and do a 'diff' to see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you were running Ubuntu desktop, try to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: all those apt-get install commans says that package not found. But when i tab it suggests and automepletes the word

Comment: Do you have python2.7*.deb in `/var/cache/apt/archives` ?

Comment: If so you could try `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7*.deb` and apt-get should work after that

Comment: the folder /var/cache/apt/archives only have "partial" inside that. NOthing else